# Creating a UITableView of the grouped style, but with square corners?

Tags: iphone

I want to keep the separated and not completely wide look of the grouped tableView, but I don't want the square corners. Is there any way to set/fake this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the `backgroundView` property on your cells to a view that looks like anything you want.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like that's how I'll have to do it, but is there any way to move the cell textLabel and accessoryView in a little? I set the frame property but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Those built in views are sort of managed for you.  You want to change where they go in a detailed way, then you must create your own subviews and add it to the cell in the spot you want.

Comment: Ok, so I'll have to create a blank cell and add my own UILabel and accessory subviews. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
cell.backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc]init] autorelease];
```