# How to remove rounded corners in a grouped table view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a UITableView of the grouped style, but with square corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554683/creating-a-uitableview-of-the-grouped-style-but-with-square-corners)

How can I remove the rounded corners from a grouped table view?

Comment: Thanks For sending the link Michael.Its working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `cell.backgroundView` property.  Set this to your custom view that doesnt contain rounded corners.