# UITableViewCell Selection Area - How to fill entire cell for top/bottom cells of a Grouped UITableView section?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, selection

I have a grouped-style UITableView. Within the tableView, I have rows arranged into sections, since the sections have variable numbers of rows. However, I have opted to push all of the sections together (for UI reasons) so that they look like one large section with multiple (expandable) rows.

The problem I am having is that I want the selection area for the top and bottom rows in each section to fill the entire cell - in other words, NOT to have the rounded corners.

I know that a plain tableview has full selection for the cells, but I cannot change from a grouped tableview to a plain tableview because that has other unwanted consequences.

I understand how to mask a the cell's selectedBackground to have rounded corners if it does not already have them, but I haven't been able to find a way to 'unround' the corners for the top and bottom cells of a section. I have created dummy rows for the bottom rows in each section, which seems to work, though it's tedious; but I can't do a dummy row for the top row since it makes that separator line too thick.

Is it possible to 'unround' the selection area of a top/bottom section row in a grouped UITableView?

EDIT TO ADD ANSWER:
The following code worked with my custom background views:

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView.bounds = cell.bounds;
```

Whatever the "shape" of the top or bottom cell of each section, as determined by the custom background view, the selection style matches the "shape" using the code above. This doesn't necessarily get rid of the rounded corners in itself, but if I set a top or bottom cell in a section to a "middle-style" cell background view (no corners) this does select the whole cell as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be a bit late , but here is what i did :

First set your cell's background view as desired and then set the cell's selected background view (to the same bounds as of cell's background)

you can specify the `cornerRadius` property , so that you can set rounding of corners as desired , i have omitted this property in my case

Here is the code to both :

```
        UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
        bg.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.980 green:0.988 blue:0.984 alpha:1];
        bg.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.827 green:0.827 blue:0.835 alpha:1].CGColor;
        bg.layer.borderWidth = kCellBorderWidth;
//        bg.layer.cornerRadius= kCellBorderRadius;
        cell.backgroundView = bg;

        // to make cell selection square and not round (which is by default)
        UIView *bg_selected = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
        bg_selected.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        bg_selected.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.827 green:0.827 blue:0.835 alpha:1].CGColor;
        bg_selected.layer.borderWidth = kCellBorderWidth;
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = bg_selected;
```

Answer (score 1):

Import the QuartzCore framework to your project.
 #import  to your tableViewController and Use following code...

**>>>edited..**

```
myTableView.layer.cornerRadius=0.0;
```

//or use your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
cell.backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds] autorelease];
```

[Square corner tableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554683/creating-a-uitableview-of-the-grouped-style-but-with-square-corners)

[Sample code and tutorial for Square corner in grouped tableview](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.in/2010/08/transparent-grouped-tableviews.html)

Hope, this will help you...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that didn't change anything as far as selection. Appreciate the answer though.

Comment: I tried your edited answer and that didn't change the selectedBackground area of the cell. Also, I checked out the link and it seems like he is adding rounded corners instead of removing them; I can remove rounded corners with a mask, but do not know how to add the missing corners back in.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the new code. Unfortunately, I am using a custom view cell the cell.backgroundView and using this just overwrites that. I tried to set the cell.selectedBackgroundView instead, and what that accomplished was to set the selected view as the actual cell background view (i.e. it didn't change color to blue, only the selected text color changed). Thanks again for working with me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to create a custom UITableViewCell, set it so that it does not clip subviews, and override the "setSelected:animated" method of the cell to show your own selection area. This is the only thing I can think of. Why can't you use a plain UITableView?

Comment: @Michael_Frederick I had a couple reasons for not being able to use a plain tableview, but the main one I can think of right now is that the separator lines extend beyond the area of the grouped tableview, and to get rid of them I would need to set the separatorStyle to none, and I actually need to have a separator style. I know that I can use a custom drawn selectedBackgroundView - I am using a custom drawn selectedBackground - but as far as performance and trying to keep to the standard selection style, I was hoping to fill the entire cell if at all possible.